# Including text file name in footer of compiled Scrivener document?

Tags: formatting, short-story, scrivener

I'm working on a short story collection using scrivener. Each story is one text file in the scrivener document.

I'd like to include the story name in the footer, next to the page number. Is that possible? Any ideas? I've tried googling around, but I can't find anything. I assume it's in the Compile > Page Settings, but I don't see it anywhere.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 4):

A little late to the table, but it may hope with future searches of this question.

The placeholder you need is:

```
<$pageGroupTitle>
```

This enables you to put a chapter title in the Page Setup, Footer during the compile.

So, provided the text file has the story name as its title, it should work.

You can see a list of all Scrivener placeholders by clicking:

`Help -> List of All Placeholders`

from the top menu. Not all placeholders are supported in headers and footers, but this one is.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, text file title isn't a "placeholder tag". BUT, I think this may work:

Make a [custom metatag](http://gwenhernandez.com/2010/12/07/tech-tuesday-custom-meta-data-in-scrivener-2-x/) in the settings. I'll call mine "Blah" for this example. Populate that with the story titles. There may be a better way to do this, but I'm not sure how.

Then in the Compile settings, under the Page Settings tab, edit the Footer field to add  .

Easy enough, and that should work.

There may be a better way where you can actually get at filenames, but I can't find it.