# Including Scrivener custom metatag in footer?

Tags: formatting, scrivener

I asked a question [here](https://writers.stackexchange.com/questions/19875/including-text-file-name-in-footer-of-compiled-scrivener-document) that I need some more details for.

I'm trying to compile I bunch of text files, and I want the names of those files in the footer. Like the answerer suggested, I added a custom metatag for each text file named `blah` which had the value of the name of the story. *But* when I got to compile, and I add `<$blah>` as something I want in the header, I just get a document that doesn't interpret that variable at all. It just says `<$blah>` brackets and dollar sign and all.

Any idea what I'm doing wrong? Or another way to accomplish this same thing?

Answer (score 1):

Hm, I think what you are trying to do, is to use a metatag like a Scrivener placeholder tag. I don't think it will work this way.

Maybe the placeholder tag `<$projecttitle>` will do the trick?

Answer (score 1):

I can't seem to figure this one out but some people on the Scrivener Forum do seem to have solved it ---- [Custom MetaData in Compile](http://literatureandlatte.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=2&t=32591&p=210759&hilit=metadata%20compile#p210759).

Hopefully you can duplicate their results.